# loop is not working after satisfying the condition

Tags: perl

I have two files myresult and annotation. details of these files are as follows.
myresult:

```
288..639 1.13075739182609-6.20035408429888i
300..651 1.90372125344918-6.09008858828515i
312..663 1.6908117147722-5.67058877579329i
324..675 0.644484787809351-5.54571698740166i
336..687 1.21850904281332-5.47700589647424i
```

annotation:

```
272..1042
1649..2629
```

For loop is running only once after satisfying the If condition. It is not entering again in loop even after the condition is satisfied. for example, in file myresult 2nd line satisfies the condition i.e numbers 300..651 lies in the range of 1st line of file annotation, therefore it prints all values from 300 to 651. But when it need to go for next round(3rd line) i.e. 312..663 it is not entering this loop since this range also lies in 1st line of file annotation.
so the output should be numbers from 300 to 663, but it is printing from 300 to 651 only.
Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Math::Complex;

open( $inp0, "<myresult" )   or die "not found";
open( $inp2, "<annotation" ) or die "not found";

my @arr2 = <$inp0>;
my @arr4 = <$inp2>;
my @result;

foreach my $line1 (@arr2) {
    my ( $col1, $col2 ) = split( /\s/, $line1 );
    if ( $col2 > 1.60 ) {
        my ( $from1, $to1 ) = split( /\.\./, $col1 );

        foreach my $line2 (@arr4) {
            my ( $from2, $to2 ) = split( /\.\./, $line2 );

            for ( my $i = $from1; $i <= $to1; $i++ ) {
                for ( my $j = $from2; $j <= $to2; $j++ ) {

                    $res = grep( /$i/, @result );
                    if ( $i == $j && $res == 0 ) {
                        print "$i \n";
                        push( @result, $i );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Second columns of the file "myresult" contains complex numbers like "1.13075739182609-6.20035408429888i" for example.

Two complex numbers can not be compared. (Complex number is a vector of complex plane with real axis and imaginary axis. Two vectors could not be compared like integer.)

'($col2>1.60)' will be false for all of your data in the file "myresult". This is why for loop is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

As Fumu said two complex numbers can not be compared.

If you need help with complex numbers in Perl then check out [Math::Complex](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/Complex.html) module.